# Pgfplots "set thousands separator" introduces errors for < 0.1

Tags: pgfplots

I don't want the `comma` as the thousand separator, so in the preamble I set

```
\pgfplotsset{
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, set thousands separator={}}
}
```

This works OK, but when I try to do a plot, where the `xmax` is under `0.1`, e.g. `0.01`, that `thousands separator` line introduces errors.

Here's the MWE: (if you put `xmax` to `0.1`, it works, at `0.01`, it doesn't)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{       
    compat=1.10,
    width=7cm,
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, set thousands separator={}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin = 0, xmax =0.01,
        ymin =-200, ymax = -20]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,-20) (0.02,-100)};
    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So how to get both: no comma as thousand separator and working code for small `x` ranges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `scaled ticks=false`. But then you will need to add `fixed,precision=3,` too to prevent xtick labels from getting cluttered.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.10,
    width=7cm,
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=3, set thousands separator={}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[scaled ticks=false,
        xmin = 0, xmax =0.01,
        ymin =-200, ymax = -20]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,-20) (0.02,-100)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: good answer, but is there any way I could have the x labels with exponents? I.e. if you take my MWE code and comment out the line starting with `x tick label...` and see the result, then that's what I want.

So basically I want everything as default except for the thousand separator to be nothing instead of a comma.

Comment: @Shepherd Then use `/pgf/number format/set thousands separator={}` as commented by egreg.

Comment: Thanks, now it works perfectly. I don't see any egreg comments though.